# Is there a known photograph of Walter Arnoldi?

Tags: mathematicians, 20th-century

A famous mathematician known for the algorithm he developed in 1950s named after him (Arnoldi Iteration Algorithm).

For my research presentation I am including photographs of pioneers of numerical linear algebra. However, there appears to be none for Arnoldi.

Comment: If you can find out where he worked, you can contact the company. Once I needed a photograph of an early century German physicist for a publication. He worked in a company and they kindly provided it free of charge. Start from here: https://www.courant.com/news/connecticut/hc-xpm-1995-10-07-9510070259-story.html

Comment: FWIW, Arnoldi does not appear to have been a mathematician. He graduated from Stevens Institute of Technology in 1937 with a degree in mechanical engineering. With the exception of W. E. Arnoldi, "The principle of minimized iterations in the solution of the matrix eigenvalue problem", *Quarterly of applied mathematics*, Vol. 9, No. 1, 1951, pp. 17-29 all his publications seem to be related to aeronautical and space engineering. Arnoldi worked for the Hamilton Standard Division of United Aircraft Corporation from 1939 to 1977 (his retirement).

Comment: I only found an incorrect one listed as him in this pdf textbook, which has Buzz Aldrin listed as Arnoldi.  It's located near section 7.5.2, or you can keyword search "arnoldi".
https://bugs.unica.it/~gppe/did/ca/tesine/16garau.pdf

Comment: @njuffa From what appears that Arnoldi was predeceased by his two children, his late wife passed away at the age of 99 in 2020.

Comment: @SPARSE I am aware from his wife's obituary. That probably means (as suggested by Achem) that your best chance of getting a hold of a picture of Arnoldi is to contact United Technologies Corporation, which became the successor to United Aircraft Corporation in 1975 (shortly before Arnoldi retired).  From what I have been able to find, Arnoldi appears to have been something like head of research at their Hamilton Standard Division around 1970, making it somewhat likely that his picture appeared in a company publication.

Comment: @SPARSE Another idea: If you can get a hold of the 1937 edition of "The Link" , the college yearbook of Stevens Institute of Technology, that likely contains a picture of Arnoldi as a member of the graduating class. Old yearbooks are occasionally available through used book sellers at reasonable prices; there are also companies that digitize them and provide online access for a fee.

Comment: I just contacted the media section of Collins Aerospace , a Raytheon Technologies subsidiary which to what I've found to be a descendent of United Aircraft Corporation. In case any information was provided (including a photo of Arnoldi) I will post it here and cite the database records of Collins Aerospace @njuffa

Comment: @njuffa I think I found it on ebay here: https://www.ebay.com/itm/233770452742. I will also try to contact the seller to see if it is possible to receive a photo of Arnoldi